# How can pow() function of C output the exact value of 2^1023 without any precision loss?

Tags: c, output, math.h

How does the following program print the exact value of 2^1023 without having any precision loss in C language?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
// Printing the value of 2 ^1023
printf("%.0f",pow(2,1023));

return 0;
}
```

Output: 89884656743115795386465259539451236680898848947115328636715040578866337902750481566354238661203768010560056939935696678829394884407208311246423715319737062188883946712432742638151109800623047059726541476042502884419075341171231440736956555270413618581675255342293149119973622969239858152417678164812112068608

Comment: Try `%g` [15 chars]

Comment: Your computer stores floating point in a format like scientific notation but with base 2 instead of 10

Answer (score 9):

Powers of two require only a **single bit** of precision. The mantissa will be just `1` (which is equivalent to two to the power of zero).

Think about it: This is because the **base** of a binary representation is `2`. In a base `10` that you're used to as a human, any power of ten needs only a single digit, e.g. `1000000 = 1 * 10^6`.

Your exponent of `1023` has 10 bits in binary notation (`11 1111 1111`), so as long as the representation of a `double` on your implementation has at least 11 bits (one more is needed for the *sign*) for the exponent, it's no surprise this number can be represented exactly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? I couldn't grasp the precision part.

Comment: a floating point number has a mantissa and an exponent. in base `10`, the number represented is `<mantissa> * 10 ^ <exponent>`. In base `2` (as computers use), it's `<mantissa> * 2 ^ <exponent>`. So your number will be stored as mantissa `1b` and exponent `11 1111 1111b`. In base `10`, multipying a number by `10` is equivalent to incrementing the exponent. The same holds for base `2` and multiplying a number by `2`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I tried the `printf("%.0f",pow(2,1023));` on gcc & overflow occurred. What could be the reason?

Comment: But does it not sound like odd that is how printf() handle such a Big integer? I mean is there any internal implementation working there?

Comment: @ShubhamBansal You mean for conversion to the decimal digits? Of course! There's some iterative algorithm doing that used by `printf()`, probably somewhat similar to the "famous" [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble#C_implementation) (but this is for integers).

Comment: @J...S maybe a different representation of `double`? I can't really tell you, it works for me using `gcc` on a linux x86_64 machine.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for replying anyways.

Comment: @J...S-- `double` is only _required_ to be able to represent a value wih base 10 exponent of at least +37; here the exponent is much larger. An implementation may of course use wider `double` than the minimum requirement.